# Could not read the contents of Desktop: Operation not permitted ~ GIMP ~ Mac ~ MacBook ~ macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, permissions, updates, gimp, macos-catalina

After recent update to macOS Catalina all programs are asking if I'm giving the right permissions for them. Unfortunately, with GIMP it was not the case and whenever I'm trying to open any file using GIMP I have the following error `Could not read the contents of Desktop. Error opening directory /Users/myuser/Desktop: Operation not permitted`, or different locations like `Downloads`, `Documents` etc. The only 1 way to open a file is currently right click of a mouse and `Open with GIMP`, it works fine. This option is limited though, for example when want to open many files.

The question is how to give the right permissions in macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me you only need to update the GIMP version https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/3710#note_659997 and that should suffice

Comment: Indeed, the one I had it was `2.10.8` and after downloading the newest `2.10.14` from https://www.gimp.org/downloads/ all folders with the `D` are working again. Thanks, accepted answer!

Comment: Not working for me in 2.10.32

Comment: @BrillPappin did you check System Preferences > Security & Privacy ?

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same issue as well. Allowing "Full Disk Access" for GIMP did not work for me (System Preferences > Security & Privacy).

What works for me is that GIMP 2.10.12 has access to the logged in user's "Pictures" folder on OS X Catalina so I just moved my photos to edit there.  It's ok as a workaround.

Comment: It's possible to access other (actually most) locations, but still the following ones not: `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Downloads`. Tried fresh installation as well as going to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` and unfortunately the same result - it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally had to fix mine earlier today, but now root folders are found under **System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy** (tab) → **Files and Folders** (not *Full Disk Access*)*.

- Network Volumes
- Downloads Folder
- Documents Folder
- Desktop Folder

*This is on **macOS Big Sur** (Version 11.4)